# For loop concept

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
def domain(email, old_domain, new_domain):
    if "@" + old_domain in email:
        index = email.index("@" + old_domain)
        new_email = email[:index] + "@" + new_domain
        return new_email
    return email
    email = ['sandeep@yahoo.com', 'maini@gmail.com', 'venky@yahoo.com', 'karupi@gmail.com']

old_domain = "yahoo.com"
new_domain = "gmail.com"
for i in email:
    print(i.domain(email, old_domain, new_domain))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/p4", line 11, in <module>
    print(i.domain(email, old_domain, new_domain))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'domain'
```

in Above coding i tried to loop the each string with the function that i define but it keep on comming error. what mistake have i done? please kindly anyone correct it.

Comment: please correct the formatting

Comment: Hi Sandeep and welcome.  Yes, your formatting needs correcting.  Also you say you get an error, but please tell us what the error is.

Comment: Your `email` is a list of strings. If `i` is one of those strings, how is `i.domain()` supposed to make sense? Strings don't have a `domain` method. Also -- your indentation seems off. Are those last 4 lines really part of your function definition?

Comment: `domain()` the method is not a member of `str` the data type that is each member of the list `email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two lines should read:

```
for i in email:
    print(domain(i, old_domain, new_domain))
```

As commented above, email is a list of strings and you need to pass each individual string.  The end result should be:

```
def domain(email, old_domain, new_domain):
    if "@" + old_domain in email:
        index = email.index("@" + old_domain)
        new_email = email[:index] + "@" + new_domain
        return new_email
    return email
email = ['sandeep@yahoo.com', 'maini@gmail.com', 'venky@yahoo.com', 'karupi@gmail.com']
old_domain = "yahoo.com"
new_domain = "gmail.com"
for i in email:
    print(domain(i, old_domain, new_domain))
```

which gives the output:

```
sandeep@gmail.com
maini@gmail.com
venky@gmail.com
karupi@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided has a few mistakes that are causing errors:

for i in email: print(i.domain(email, old_domain, new_domain))
Here you are trying to access the function domain() as a method of the string i, however domain() is a separate function and it is not a method of the string.
So instead of i.domain(email, old_domain, new_domain) use domain(i, old_domain, new_domain)

Also email is already defined as a list, you don't need to pass it again as an argument in the domain() function

On top of that, you don't need a list of email to iterate through, you can directly pass it one by one, So instead of passing the whole list of emails, you need to pass one email at a time

Here's the corrected version of the code:

```
def domain(email, old_domain, new_domain):
if "@" + old_domain in email:
    index = email.index("@" + old_domain)
    new_email = email[:index] + "@" + new_domain
    return new_email
return email
```

email = ['sandeep@yahoo.com', 'maini@gmail.com', 'venky@yahoo.com', 'karupi@gmail.com']
old_domain = "yahoo.com"
new_domain = "gmail.com"
for i in email:
print(domain(i, old_domain, new_domain))